# Method called when a user is authenticated

Tags: identityserver4, duende-identity-server

We are running Duende IdentityServer4 (latest IdentityServer4) with SAML2 authentication for a 3rd party client.
What I want to accomplish is:

- The user is logged in on our IdentityServer.
- When the user jumps to the 3rd party client, the user is authenticated by us and the username is sent to the client.
- Just before the username is sent (after the authentication) I need to check that the user exists in the client. If the user doesn't exist, I will create it before the authenticated username is sent back to the client.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It is important to realize that IdentityServer does not care how the user is authenticated, instead that is up to you and typically handled in the AccountController. The following picture shows my mental model:

[image]

So, in your case I would just add that check in the AccountController class before the user is signed in.

Comment: Yes, I have full control over that scenario.
The problem comes when the user is logged in and authenticated from the client through SAML2.
Scenario:
The user is logged in.
The user click a button that links to the 3rd party client.
3rd party authenticates the user via SAML2 to get the username
The user is then logged in in the 3rd party client.
Before the username is sent back in the authentication answer, I want to make sure the the user exists at the client site.

Comment: I'd add an intermediate broadly like so:
1. Configure the SAML2 external IDP to sign into a temporary external cookie auth scheme
2. When triggering the SAML2 flow ensure that the redirect URL (in AuthenticationProperties) is set that the URL of the intermediate action
3. In the intermediate action authenticate the temp external scheme, do any processing you need to and then continue by redirecting back to the original /connect/authorize URL

Comment: Also, do look at the ExternalController.cs class, as that one is tailored for authenticating with thirdparty services.

Comment: Hej Tommy, so do you want me to clarify something else or are you happy with my answer?